# install4j: Deleting files from the home directory of the invoked root user

Tags: install4j

My application creates a folder that the installer does not, therefore I need to figure out how to remove these files. The only problem, is that the uninstaller is ran as root. So when I try to purge these files with an action and try to point it to the invoking user (in this case, it's root), it tries to remove these additional files in the `/root/` directory. These files, however, are created and stored in the `/home/user` directory.

I've looked around on the install4j page and cannot find a way to detect the invoking sudo user. In shell, this can be achieved by calling `logname`. Is there anyway (natively) to detect the user executing the uninstall as root via install4j uninstaller?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a "Run executable or batch file" action with the "Executable" set to "/usr/bin/logname", "Redirect stdout" to "To installer variable". Then you get the output of the command in the configured installer variable.

Comment: Hah! Clever. Thank you for this. Will try it and report back.

Comment: I have a feeling I am doing something wrong. I have Executable set to `/usr/bin/logname`, Working dir set to `.`, and redirect stdout to `var` set to `lognameUser`. I have a delete file action trying to remove the folder `/home/${installer:lognameUser}/.tls` but it never gets deleted. The uninstall log says that the logname execution returned no value which explains why it's trying to remove `/home/.tls`. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the uninstall log?

Comment: In the log file: `Property executable: /usr/bin/logname` - `Property stdoutVariableName: logname`. After the action completes, it says `[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.launching.LaunchHelper: stdout output was empty`. So there is no output of /usr/bin/logname. The machine that this is being executed on does in fact have that path. I'm not sure why it's having trouble executing it.

Comment: I redirected the stderr for the action to the log file and I'm getting this: `/usr/bin/logname: no login name`. Makes sense to why stdout is empty.